# How to set response status code in route with type json in odoo 14

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, response, httpresponse, json-rpc

I have created a route with type Json in odoo 14.

```
@http.route('/test', auth='public', methods=['POST'], type="json", csrf=False)
def recieve_data(self, **kw):
       headers = request.httprequest.headers
       args = request.httprequest.args
       data = request.jsonrequest
```

So when I receive request using this route everything is fine, but suppose I want to return a different status code like 401, I could not do that with the route which type is json.
I have also tried the bellow method but the problem with this method is that it stops all odoo future requests.

```
from odoo.http import request, Response
@http.route('/test', auth='public', methods=['POST'], type="json", csrf=False)
def recieve_data(self, **kw):
      headers = request.httprequest.headers
      args = request.httprequest.args 
      data = request.jsonrequest
      Response.status = "401 unauthorized"
      return {'error' : 'You are not allowed to access the resource'}
```

So in the above example If I set the response status code to 401 all other requests even if they are to different routes will be stopped and its status code changes 401 .
I have checked this problem in both odoo14 and odoo13.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot specify the code of the response, as you can see the status code is hardcoded in `http.py`:

```
def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):

   # ......
   # ......

    return Response(
        body, status=error and error.pop('http_status', 200) or 200,
        headers=[('Content-Type', mime), ('Content-Length', len(body))]
    )
```

If the result is not an error the status code is always `200`. but you can change the code of the method directly or use a monkey patch witch if it's not really important to specify the code of status in the result don't do ti ^^.

A simple monkey patch put this in `__init__.py` of the module that you want this behavior in it.

```
from odoo.http import JsonRequest

class JsonRequestPatch(JsonRequest):

    def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):
        response = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
            }
        default_code = 200
        if error is not None:
            response['error'] = error
        if result is not None:
            response['result'] = result
            # you don't want to remove some key of another result by mistake
            if isinstance(response, dict)
                defautl_code = response.pop('very_very_rare_key_here', default_code)

        mime = 'application/json'
        body = json.dumps(response, default=date_utils.json_default)

        return Response(
            body, status=error and error.pop('http_status', defautl_code ) or defautl_code,
            headers=[('Content-Type', mime), ('Content-Length', len(body))]
        )
        
        
JsonRequest._json_response = JsonRequestPatch._json_response
```

and in the result of JSON api you can change the code of status like this

```
 def some_controler(self, **kwargs):
        result = ......
        result['very_very_rare_key_here'] = 401
        return result
```

The risk in monkey patching is you override the method compeletly and if some change is done in Odoo in new version you have to do you it in your method too.
The above code is from `odoo 13.0` I did a lot of this when I build a restfull module to work with a website uses `axios` witch don't allow sending body in `GET` request. and odoo expect the argument to be inside the body in `json` request.

Comment: Thank you the answer worked absolutely fine. When I send a request from postman for example its fine. But it throws error if I open the module interface. so to handle that I just added a try and catch.                                                                                 
           try:
                if 'custom_status_code' in result:
                    default_code = result.pop('custom_status_code', default_code)
            except Exception as e:
                _logger.warning("Custom Json Request Handling {}".format(str(e)))

Comment: My mistake forget that  response could be a direct dictionary or list of dictoinary, I think verifying the type of reponse will do the trick to avoid logging warning that you don't need in your log file. Check my edits you will get the idea

Comment: DUDE!!!! I wish i could give you a bro hug!!! Thank you so much. you just help me from my hours struggling :)

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of completion, here is a minor fix based on the comment of Charif DZ.

You have to pop your custom http-Status from result and not from response.

But many thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Is working in Odoo 14 and should also work with Odoo 13 as the original _json_response method is the same.

```
from odoo.http import JsonRequest, Response
from odoo.tools import date_utils

class JsonRequestPatch(JsonRequest):

    def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):
        response = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
            }
        default_code = 200
        if error is not None:
            response['error'] = error
        if result is not None:
            response['result'] = result
            # you don't want to remove some key of another result by mistake
            if isinstance(result, dict):
                default_code = result.pop('very_very_rare_key_here', default_code)

        mime = 'application/json'
        body = json.dumps(response, default=date_utils.json_default)

        return Response(
            body, status=error and error.pop('http_status', default_code) or default_code,
            headers=[('Content-Type', mime), ('Content-Length', len(body))]
        )
        
        
JsonRequest._json_response = JsonRequestPatch._json_response
```

the controller logic remains the same as above

```
 def some_controller(self, **kwargs):
        result = ......
        result['very_very_rare_key_here'] = 401
        return result
```